# TinyMCE do not auto convert a URL into a link on Paste

Tags: url, tinymce, paste

When I paste a URL into a TinyMCE editor it converts the text into a  link.

So `http://vimeo.com/18150336` would be come `<a href="http://vimeo.com/18150336">http://vimeo.com/18150336</a>`. I would like to keep the plain text. Is their a way to configure TinyMCE to keep the link as plain text.

I do not want to strip out  tags as adding a hyperlinks should be an option on the toolbar. It should just not happen by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [paste plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste) and the setting `paste_preprocessing` in order to keep the plain text. You might need to check inside the function specified using `paste_preprocessing` if you got a link or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is the TinyMCE plugin `autolink` which is responsible for automatically creating links on paste. (And write).

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/autolink/

Answer (score 0):

It's been 5 years, So I'm probably using a newer version of TinyMCE, anyway this solution worked for me, Just add this option:

```
paste_preprocess: function(plugin, args) {
    args.content += ' ';
}
```

So when you initialize the tinymce, it should be something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "paste",
  paste_preprocess: function(plugin, args) {
    args.content += ' ';
  }
});
```

[This is the page of documentation for TinyMCE V4](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/)